# Creating pipe jumps in ArcMap

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcmap, editing

When recording underground water pipes in the GIS we typically show where pipes cross (but don't join) with a pipe jump - a little half loop in one of the lines, something like this

[image]

On my main work computer I have Esri's "[Water Utility Network Editing](https://solutions.arcgis.com/utilities/water/help/network-editing/tools/overview-network-editing-tools/)" toolbar, which includes a tool to "Create Over Jumps for Selected Lines" which works really well.

[image]

However, I am currently working on another company's computer, and I am unable to have any changes made, toolbars installed, etc., and don't have access to this tool.

Is there a built-in tool already somewhere in ArcMap (10.6) that will do this, or something with similar functionality?

I am working with supplied data - essentially existing lines - and not new lines that I am capturing myself.

Currently my process is to:

1. Create a circle over where I want the jump
2. Split the circle where it intersects with the line
3. Delete the portion of the circle not needed
4. Split the line where it intersects with the circle
5. Delete the portion of the line not needed
6. Select the two parts of the line, and the circle, and merge together into one feature

Comment: This task is easy to automate, but I hope you are doing this on a copy of original for presentation purposes only, because changing geometry might cause big problems if someone use them for modeling purposes.

Comment: @FelixIP I'm interested in how you would automate (on a system you can make no changes on)?

Comment: And unless you're putting jumps on every single line in the network, these small jumps are unlikely to have much impact on models versus the inherent inaccuracy of how the data is obtained.

Comment: I gave it a go and realized that some scripting required, set of standard tools is not enough. BTW some modelers won't like it (good luck trying to explain messy character of inputs), what they will see is a doubling of pipe volume (as per your picture) and huge hydraulic losses at sharp turns of the pipe.

Answer (score 1):

See the mini movie below, you can create a pipe jump as you draw the line by inserting an arc segment. You do this by swapping between sketch tools. This is using the standard editing tools in ArcMap and requires no customisation. It takes a little bit of effort to get the sequence correct and you can set the radius by pressing the R key.

[image: Editing]

Comment: Thanks for this, but I should have been more clear in my question - these are not lines I'm drawing in, they are supplied to me (so essentially existing lines).